# Uncaught Typeerror: undefined is not a function error1

Tags: jquery

I am getting the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function Hello.html:30createSite Hello.html:30(anonymous function) Hello.html:22j jquery-latest.min.js:2k.fireWith jquery-latest.min.js:2m.extend.ready jquery-latest.min.js:2J

Below is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Hello</h1>

 <script>

 $(function() {

     var Site = { 
             id: 3, 
             name: "JSON test Site",
             latitude: 12.23, 
             longitude: 23.34
             };

     createSite(Site);
 });

 function createSite(Site) {
     $.ajax({

         url : "api/site",
         type : "post",
         data: JSON.Stringify(Site),
         dataType: "json",
         contentype: "application/json",
         success: function(response) {
             console.log(response);  
         },

        error: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }


     }); 

 }

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is case sensitive `JSON.Stringify(Site)` should be `JSON.stringify(Site)`(lowercase "s")